# Extracting data-row value into variable if element exists

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Basically what I need to do is if specific element exists, extract data-row value into a variable based on the row that is in.

This is what I have so far.

```
if (drive.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(., 'Automation')]")).Displayed)
{
    // Code to extract the variable
}
```

As you can see from the code below and above, i need to check if the text Automation is there(Which i did above). Then, i need to extract the data-row value into a variable.

```
 <td id="browse_row28_col0" style="text-align:left;" class="browseDataCell column0 " data-row="28" data-column="0" onmousedown="event.preventDefault()">
    <div style="width:200px;" class="dontWrapData ">Automation</div>
 </td>
```

The thing i'm having issue with is I am not sure how to extract the data from that because the value of data-row will never be the same. I don't know how to extract the data-row value based on the TD tag that div "automation" is in.

I apologize if i did a poor job explaining what i need help with. If you have any questions, please do ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the `<td>` element and use get attribute to extract data-row

```
string dataRow = drive.FindElement(By.Id("browse_row28_col0")).GetAttribute("data-row");
```

In `if(drive.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(., 'Automation')]")).Displayed)` you don't check if the element exist, but if the element is displayed.

To check if the element exist you can set implicit wait

```
drive.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

And to check if the element is visible you should use explicit wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(drive, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
WebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("[class*='dontWrapData']")));
```

You can also use explicit wait for exist

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("[class*='dontWrapData']")));
```

The `CssSelector` will search for class attribute witch contains "dontWrapData".
I didn't use `By.ClassName` because of the white space in the html `class="dontWrapData "`.

The waits will wait up to 10 seconds for the element to exist/be visible.

> Edit

To find the data-row by "Automation" text you can put all rows in list and search for child element with the text

```
string dataRow = string.Empty;
IList<IWebElement> rows = drive.FindElements(By.CssSelector("[id*='browse_row']"));
foreach (IWebElement row in rows)
{
    IWebElement div = row.findElement(By.CssSelector("[class*='dontWrapData']"));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(div.Text) && div.Text.Equals("Automation"))
    {
        dataRow = row.GetAttribute("data-row");
    }
}
```

You can find all the `<td>` tags by common partial ID, and check for each one if he has child element with "Automation" text. If it does you can extract the "data-row".

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work.The reason it doesnt is because i can't implicitly search by the ID. Because the ID will change depending on which row the "automation" is in. The id could be browse_row1_col0 or it could be browse_row924_col0. 

This is why i need to find which row the automation is in.

Comment: @Travis I added solution for that scenario under Edit in my answer.